# How can I access session inside codeigniter using android volley plus

Tags: android, codeigniter

I Im using "Volley plus" library to make multipart form data as "volley plus" is easier to use i was success with with login and signup but when i access my home controller it throws be back to login page because session is not set

I tried to find answer every one refer to use cookies i didn't get with volley plus

can you add code preview i am just starter to android

Thanks

Comment: If session does not work, you may need to use token. If user login successfully, generate a token and store it in some table like `tokens` and return the token to android app. Your android app save it and send it together with all requests. Your server must check that token is valid or not, and return data.

Comment: sessions are working fine when i access my website on web browser, but when i make request from android "volley plus" library the session are not setting

Comment: I recommend using token to solve your problem.